# Cannot convert from T1 to T2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to display selected items from a ~/folder/pages to root page name Product in asp.net 2015, I have displayed all items in a page already but as i call the model class there is an error "`cannot implicitly convert type`" and few errors like

> Error CS1503 Argument 1: `cannot convert from
>   'SAIT_Electronics.Pages.Product' to 'SAIT_Electronics.Product

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SAIT_Electronics.Models;
using System.Collections;
using System.Management;
using SAIT_Electronics.Pages;
namespace SAIT_Electronics.Pages
{
 public partial class Product : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fillpage();
        }

        private void Fillpage()
        {
            //get selected products data
            if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                productmodel model = new productmodel();
                Product product = model.GetProduct(id);
                //fill page with data
                lblPrice.Text = "Price per unit : <br/>$" + product.Price;
                                lblTitle.Text = product.Name;
                lblDescription.Text = product.Description;
                lblItemNr.Text = id.ToString();
                imgProduct.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;
                //fill amount dropdownlist with number 1 -10
                int[] amount = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
                ddlAmount.DataSource = amount;
                ddlAmount.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlAmount.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[here is attached error picture of asp.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFuwk.jpg)

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using SAIT_Electronics.Models;




namespace SAIT_Electronics.Pages.Management
{
    public partial class ManageProducts : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ImagesFolder();

                //check if the url contains an id parameter
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                    FillPage(id);
                }
            }
                
        }


        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            productmodel ProductModel = new productmodel();
            Product product = CreateProduct();

            //check if the url contains an id parameter
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                //id exist -> update existing row
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                lblResults.Text = ProductModel.UpdateProduct(id, product);
            }

            else
            {
                //id does not exist -> create a new row
                lblResults.Text = ProductModel.InsertProduct(product);
            }
                
        }

        private void FillPage(int id)
        {
            // get selected products from db 
            productmodel ProductModel = new productmodel();
            Product product = ProductModel.GetProduct(id);

            //fill text boxes
            txtDescription.Text = product.Description;
            txtName.Text = product.Name;
            txtPrice.Text = product.Price.ToString();

            //set dropdown list values
            ddImage.SelectedValue = product.Image;
            ddType.SelectedValue = product.TypeId.ToString();
        }


        private void ImagesFolder()
        {
            try
            {
                //get all file paths
                //string[] images = Directroy.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));
                // string[] images = Server.MapPath(@"/Images/Products/");
                string[] images = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));
                // String  images = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Desktop\Shoping\SAIT_Electronics\SAIT_Electronics\Images\Products\").Name;

                //string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(("~/D:/Desktop/Shoping/SAIT_Electronics/SAIT_Electronics/Images/Products/"), "*.xml");
                //get all file names and add them to an arraylist
                ArrayList imageList = new ArrayList();
                foreach (string image in images )
                {
                    string imageName = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                    imageList.Add(imageName);
                }

                // set the array list as dropdwon views datasouce and refresh
                ddImage.DataSource = imageList;
                ddImage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddImage.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lblResults.Text = e.ToString();
            }
        }


        private Product CreateProduct()
        {
            Product product = new Product();

            product.Name = txtName.Text;
            product.Price = Decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
            product.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(ddType.SelectedValue);
            product.Description = txtDescription.Text;
            product.Image = ddImage.SelectedValue;

            return product;
        }

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the return type of model.GetProduct(id) to Product

Comment: You method `model.GetProduct(id);` must be returning a different type (maybe _product_ but not this one). Here it is referncing to current page `Product` so change the type or specify it with full namespace.

Comment: yes the error remove by this but convert error remain same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Product` type in this line

```
Product product = model.GetProduct(id);
```

is the `Product` class you're inside right now, thus `SAIT_Electronics.Pages.Product`. Try this:

```
SAIT_Electronics.Product product = model.GetProduct(id);
```

or simply this:

```
var product = model.GetProduct(id);
```

You should do the same in your ManageProducts.aspx.cs file. Wherever you define a variable of type `Product`, replace `Product` with `SAIT_Electronics.Product`. For instance line 39 becomes:

```
SAIT_Electronics.Product product = CreateProduct();
```

The same goes for lines 61, 106 and 108.

Comment: thanks Vicari for your quick reply... by using these change i am able to remove errors but this error as same....... "Cannot convert from 'SAIT_Electronics.Pages.Product' to 'SAIT_Electronics.Product' "

Comment: I see. The error is not in the file you posted (Products.aspx.cs) but in another file (ManageProducts.aspx.cs). Could you post the relevant methods/lines?

Comment: actually i have products on index page and want to on next page with details and add to cart button after click on it.

Comment: I assume the ManageProducts class is in the same namespace as the class you posted above (thus SAIT_Electronics.Pages). If that is the case, when you write `Product` the compiler thinks `SAIT_Electronics.Pages.Product`, not `SAIT_Electronics.Product`. Try replacing all instances of `Product` in ManageProducts.aspx.cs with `SAIT_Electronics.Product`, then if you still get errors post the entire content of the ManageProducts.aspx.cs directly in your question.

Comment: thanx Emilio vicari